# Как вернуть полосочки в области редактора в PHPStorm 2022.3.3

Tags: phpstorm, ide

Сидел на 2020 версии phpstorm'a, сегодня перешел на 2020.3.3, у меня пропали полоски в разделе работы с кодом, как можно их вернуть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно помочь через включение:

```
Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance | Show method separators
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо через:

```
Settings/Preferences - Editor | Color Scheme | General - Code | Method separator color
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]